# Restricted Permutations with repetitions in R

Tags: r, permutation

Suppose my data has 2 columns with
col1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
col2 <- c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

I want to generate all possible repetitions of the elements of col1 subject to

- the total length is 6,
- the order (1 =<2 =< 3) on col1 and col2 are preserved, and
- no element of col1 is removed.

(Thus c(1,1, 2, 3, 3, 3) would be OK

How is this done in R with the 'permute' or 'gtools' libray?  My real data set has ~10 columns and < 60000 rows.

I checked the documentation.

Comment: Can you provide additional examples of your desired output? As it stands, your question is unclear.

Comment: My desired output is like in jblood94's answer below.

Comment: Remember to accept his answer if it helped you, which ensures that others have quick access to information.

Answer (score 2):

Each element is repeated by the order 3 integer compositions of 6. Using the `compositions` function from the `partitions` package:

```
col1 <- 1:3
n <- 6L
parts <- partitions::compositions(n, length(col1), FALSE)
matrix(rep.int(rep(col1, ncol(parts)), parts), n)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#> [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#> [2,]    1    1    1    2    1    1    2    1    2     2
#> [3,]    1    1    2    2    1    2    2    2    2     3
#> [4,]    1    2    2    2    2    2    2    3    3     3
#> [5,]    2    2    2    2    3    3    3    3    3     3
#> [6,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3
```